# composer.json for bjy-authorize, zfcUser and zfc-user-doctrine-orm in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, zfcuser

i am trying to use bjy-authorize, zfcUser and zfc-user-doctrine-orm in ZF2 using the composer.
But i always get an error, when i call composer.phar update.

the composer.json looks as follows:

```
    {
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-base": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "dev-master"
}
}
```

I tried it without the last 3 lines (starting with "zf-commons) The i get no error, but the zfc-user-doctrine module is not installed.

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
    Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1
- Conclusion: remove bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize dev-master|install zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize dev-master|remove zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master|install zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1
- Installation request for bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize dev-master -> satisfiable by bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize dev-master.
- bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize dev-master requires zf-commons/zfc-user dev-master -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-user dev-master, zf-commons/zfc-user dev-master.
- zf-commons/zfc-user dev-master requires zf-commons/zfc-base 0.* -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.0, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.0.
- zf-commons/zfc-user dev-master requires zf-commons/zfc-base 0.* -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.0, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.0.
- Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.0.
- Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.0.
- Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master
```

What do i have to change in the composer.json file?

Best,
iceman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your `composer.json` as following:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "~0.7",
        "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "~1.1",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "~0.1",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "~0.1"
    }
}
```

Avoid using `dev-master` if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I also tried this solution and it is working, too. I am using this now, because it includes the zfcUser module. **Thanks**

Comment: @Ocramius are these the recommended settings, to this day? I'm having some errors loading the registration page in `Zfcuser` and I'm not sure if it's linked to these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Zf-Commons have started tagging their releases. If I were you I'd remove zfc-user, zfc-base, and doctrine-orm-module.

Change bjy-authorize's version from dev-master to 1.* and zfc-user-doctrine-orm to 0.*. Composer should then handle the dependencies from there.

Comment: Removing those modules is not correct, since his application is most probably referencing them somehow.